# Suggestions on making the code read the csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I have this code for a discord bot that allows moderation staff to go on leave and then return, the command takes away their moderation role and gives them a leave role, however there are seniority levels of staff, so each have their own command for it.

The code is supposed to log the ID of the user who used that command into a specific CSV file, however on the returning command I don't believe it's storing or reading the file for the id, i.e. a moderator can use their command to go on leave however they can then use an admin return command giving them an admin role.

I believe this is because the code isn't reading or writing in the desired files, this is the code I have;

```py
    @client.command()
    @commands.has_role('Moderator')
    async def slm(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        if not member:
            member = ctx.author
        loa = ctx.guild.get_role(848032714715561985)
        mod = ctx.guild.get_role(848032880709074944)
        await member.add_roles(loa)
        await member.remove_roles(mod)
        file = open("modRecord.csv", "w")
        file.write(str(ctx.author.id))
        file.close()
        await ctx.send("I have filed your Leave, take care, we look forward to your return!")
    
    
    @client.command()
    async def srm(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        if not member:
            member = ctx.author
        mod = ctx.guild.get_role(848032880709074944)
        loa = ctx.guild.get_role(848032714715561985)
        found = False
        with open('modRecord.csv', 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                if row[0] == str(ctx.author.id):
                    found = True
                    break
        if found is False:
            await member.add_roles(mod)
            await member.remove_roles(loa)
            await ctx.send("Welcome back!")
        else:
            await ctx.send("We do not have history of you having a Moderator role.")
```

the command for the other moderator roles are the same except a different file to store their id's, each command has their own file essentially.

Could anyone tell me why it's not reading or writing in the files, or suggest a better recording system?

Comment: Typically a database is preferred for application storage over a csv

Comment: It would help if you broke that wall of text into paragraphs, and used punctuation to properly end sentences so that it's clear where one sentence ends, and a new one begins. Sentences end with a `.`, and the first word of the next sentence should be capitalized. I'd have tried to fix it, but I'm afraid doing so would cause a mistake in what you're asking. You should [edit] to address those issues.

Answer (score 0):

A Database is indeed a better way for storing such data, but there is no such problem in using CSV. I found 1 mistake that every time you are storing member/author id you are using "Write" mode while opening it.

```
file = open("modRecord.csv", "w")
file.write(str(ctx.author.id))
```

This clears all previous data present in your csv and then write new one.
Here are are some other possible ways to it:

**Use Append Mode**: By this you can add the id at the last of the file.

```
file = open("modRecord.csv", 'a')
file.write(str(ctx.author.is))
file.close()
```

**Use pandas**: Pandas is a python library, easily capable to read/write csv files. Use it treat csv like a spreadsheet. There are other libraries too like Openpyxl. But I prefer pandas.

**First Read and then Write file**: First read the file, store it's contents in a variable, make any iterations that you want to make in the content like replacing any row, deleting any row, adding a row in between two rows, etcetera and then finally write the variable again into the file.

```
file=open('modRecord.csv','r')
file_content=file.read()
make changes in file_content
new_file=open('modRecord.csv','w')
new_file.write(file_content)
file.close()
new_file.close()
```